# Just not able to install Web3 through powershell

Tags: web3js, truffle, dapps, javascript, ethereumj

After reading a lot of articles about how to install Web3j in windows. 
I also tried following this article : https://kauri.io/generate-a-java-wrapper-from-your-smart-contract/84475132317d4d6a84a2c42eb9348e4b/a

I ran the following commands in Power shell `npm install web3` `npm install -g node-gyp`

I got the following error :
[image]

I wanted to use Web3j to get the Javascript wrapper class for my smart contract which i had deployed using truffle and ganche-cli.

Could someone please assist me on how can I get the Javascript wrapper class for my smart contract, using powershell?

I really need some quick help, please help me out, i have a project submission due.

Thanks in advance!

Tried this as well:

[image]

Comment: It happens very often that latest node versions are buggy. I'm have installed node v10.6.0 with npm ```v6.1.0``` and so far I don't have problem installing ```web3``` or any other npm package. You can find previous node versions at https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Comment: Hey, tried with the version you mentioned, but im still getting the same error :(